# Customize Spring Security rendering page, when an authorization fails, Grails

Tags: spring, grails, spring-security

For example I have a gsp-pages, which I want to render when authorization via Spring Security in Grails fail. At the moment I want to proccess two fail causes:

```
1) Password and login combination is incorrect
2) User have not neccessary permissions to view page
```

How to do it?

This is my LoginController:

```
@Secured(['permitAll'])
class LoginController {
    def auth() { 
        render (view:'auth.gsp')
    }
}
```

This is authorization form in gsp-page:

```
<form class="form-signin" action='/restorator/j_spring_security_check' method='POST' id='loginForm'>
        <h2 class="form-signin-heading">Login</h2>
        <div class="text-left">
            <small>Login</small>
        </div>        
        <label for="username" class="sr-only">Login</os-p></label>
        <input id="username" name='j_username' class="form-control" placeholder="Login" required="" autofocus="" type="text">
        <div class="text-left">
            <small>Password</small>
        </div>
        <label for="password" class="sr-only">Password</label>
        <input id="password" class="form-control" name='j_password' data-translatable-string="Password" type="password">
        <div class="checkbox">
          <label data-replace-tmp-key="2c2fb6d9630510f8721fb57d8c90d50c"><os-p key="2c2fb6d9630510f8721fb57d8c90d50c"><input value="remember-me" type="checkbox" class='chk' name='_spring_security_remember_me' id='remember_me'>Remember me</os-p></label>
        </div>
        <button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" type="submit"  id="submit" >Enter</button>
</form>
```

Spring Security config:

```
// Added by the Spring Security Core plugin:
grails.plugin.springsecurity
grails.plugin.springsecurity.logout.postOnly = false
grails.plugin.springsecurity.userLookup.userDomainClassName = 'restorator.auth.Person'
grails.plugin.springsecurity.userLookup.authorityJoinClassName = 'restorator.auth.PersonAuthority'
grails.plugin.springsecurity.authority.className = 'restorator.auth.Authority'
grails.plugin.springsecurity.controllerAnnotations.staticRules = [
    '/':                              ['permitAll'],
    '/index':                         ['permitAll'],
    '/index.gsp':                     ['permitAll'],
    '/assets/**':                     ['permitAll'],
    '/**/js/**':                      ['permitAll'],
    '/**/css/**':                     ['permitAll'],
    '/**/images/**':                  ['permitAll'],
    '/**/fonts/**':                   ['permitAll'],
    '/**/favicon.ico':                ['permitAll'],
    '/startPage':                     ['permitAll'],
    '/dbconsole/**':                  ['permitAll'],
    '/publicCafeeView':               ['permitAll'],
    '/publicCafeeInfo':               ['permitAll']
]
```

Comment: show your security config

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in your config 3 lines are missing:

1. failed authentication (login):

> grails.plugin.springsecurity.failureHandler.defaultFailureUrl = '/login?loginError=true'

2. wrong authorization (wrong permissions):

> grails.plugin.springsecurity.adh.errorPage = '/login/denied'
>    grails.plugin.springsecurity.adh.ajaxErrorPage = '/login/denied'

these 2 lines are default mapping. You can simply put your 'denied.gsp' into the `/login` dir, and it will be picked automatically